# Function for counting and adding new columns in a data frame in R

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have data sets like these with different row numbers. But the task seems very complicated to me. I end up with having empty columns.

```r
ID <- c("0001", "0002", "0003", "0004", "0008", "0009")
class <- c("0010", "0011", "0100", "0101", "0110", "0111")
user <- c(letters[1:6])
name <- c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F")

df1 <- data.frame(ID, class, name, user)

ID <- c("0001", "0002", "0002", "0003", "0004", "0008", "0010")
class <- c("0010", "0011", "0011", "0100", "0101", "0110", "0112")
name <- c("A", "B", "B", "C", "D", "E", "G")
user <- c(letters[1:7])
df2 <- data.frame(ID, class, name, user)

ID <- c("0001", "0002", "0003", "0004", "0009")
class <- c("0010", "0011", "0100", "0101", "0111")
name <- c("A", "unknown", "C", "unknown", "F")
user <- c(letters[1:5])
df3 <- data.frame(ID, class, name, user)

ID <- c("0001", "0002", "0003", "0004", "0008", "0010")
class <- c("1010", "0011", "0100", "0101", "0110", "0112")
name <- c("A", "b", "C", "unknown", "E", "G")
user <- c(letters[1:6])
df4 <- data.frame(ID, class, name, user)
```

<sup>Created on 2021-07-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

I want to have a output like this:

```r
ID <- c("0001", "0001", "0002", "0003", "0004", "0008", "0009", "0010")
class <- c("0010", "1010", "0011", "0100", "0101", "0110", "0111", "0112")
name <- c("A", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G")
count_of_ID_class_combination_use <- c(3, 1, 4, 4, 4, 3, 2, 2)
total_df_analyzed <- c(4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4)
List_of_df_that_use_this <- c("df1_df2_df3", "df4", "df1_df2_df3_df4", "df1_df2_df3_df4", "df1_df2_df3_df4", "df1_df2_df3_df4", "df1_df3", "df2_df4")
Other_names_used <- c("", "", "unknown_b", "", "unknown", "", "", "")
main <- data.frame(ID, class, name, count_of_ID_class_combination_use, total_df_analyzed, List_of_df_that_use_this, Other_names_used)
```

<sup>Created on 2021-07-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

I want to compare `df1` with other dfs. At first, I want to check if any `ID` and `class` combinations is used multiple time. I will ignore them (like `0002` and `0011` combination in `df2`). Then considering `ID`, `class` and `name`, I want to know how many times a particular `ID` and `class` combination was used, total number of data frame analysed, list of the data frames that used that combination, and other names (if more than one name for the same `ID` and `class` combination).

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Making use of `dplyr` this could be achieved like so:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(string)

# First: Put the df in one list
df_list <- mget(paste0("df", 1:4))

df_bind <- dplyr::bind_rows(df_list, .id = "df_id")
df_bind %>% 
  # Remove duplicated observations per df
  distinct(ID, class, name, df_id) %>% 
  mutate(total_df_analyzed = n_distinct(df_id)) %>% 
  group_by(ID, class) %>% 
  # Summary stats per ID and class
  mutate(count_of_ID_class_combination_use = n(),
         List_of_df_that_use_this = paste(df_id, collapse = "_"),
         Other_names_used = paste(unique(name), collapse = "_")) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  # Keep only one row per ID and class
  distinct(ID, class, .keep_all = TRUE) %>% 
  mutate(Other_names_used = stringr::str_remove(Other_names_used, paste0(name, "(_)?"))) %>% 
  select(ID, class, name, count_of_ID_class_combination_use, total_df_analyzed, List_of_df_that_use_this,Other_names_used) %>% 
  arrange(ID, class) %>% 
  as.data.frame()
#>     ID class name count_of_ID_class_combination_use total_df_analyzed
#> 1 0001  0010    A                                 3                 4
#> 2 0001  1010    A                                 1                 4
#> 3 0002  0011    B                                 4                 4
#> 4 0003  0100    C                                 4                 4
#> 5 0004  0101    D                                 4                 4
#> 6 0008  0110    E                                 3                 4
#> 7 0009  0111    F                                 2                 4
#> 8 0010  0112    G                                 2                 4
#>   List_of_df_that_use_this Other_names_used
#> 1              df1_df2_df3                 
#> 2                      df4                 
#> 3          df1_df2_df3_df4        unknown_b
#> 4          df1_df2_df3_df4                 
#> 5          df1_df2_df3_df4          unknown
#> 6              df1_df2_df4                 
#> 7                  df1_df3                 
#> 8                  df2_df4
```